# Do the Maxwell equations yield the proper time of electromagnetic waves?

Tags: special-relativity, maxwell-equations

I apologize in advance for possible errors in my premises as I have no precise knowledge of Maxwell equations. Proposals for the correction or even abandon of my question are welcome.

As Maxwell equations are a full description of electromagnetic waves I suppose that they also describe the **time** a wave takes from the place of its emission to the place of absorption. My question: As Maxwell equations are relativistically invariant (or at least compatible with special relativity), do they also yield the **proper time** (which is always zero for electromagnetic waves in vacuum)?

Comment: Proper time is not a property of waves or particles, it is a property of paths in spacetime. That paths that represent motions with the speed of light (which is indeed predicted by the theory of electromagnetism) have zero proper time is a direct consequence of the way the Minkowski metric works.

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/122735/2451

Comment: @ACuriousMind: Thank you for this information. I agree that Maxwell equations are taking into account Minkowski spacetime as they are Lorentz-invariant. They describe time and distance of waves, but do they also take into account the fact that the spacetime interval of electromagnetic waves is zero? - Also, a photon is not aging and the age seems to be a property of particles.

Comment: Though there is no proper time, I belive that it's possible to define an affine parameter to an photon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Maxwell equations don't need to "take into account" that the proper time of light-like paths is zero.

The *definition* of the Minkowski metric as

$$\mathrm{d}s^2 = c^2\mathrm{d}t^2 - \mathrm{d}x^2 - \mathrm{d}y^2 - \mathrm{d}z^2$$

[Lorentz invariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_invariance) means that all physical laws are invariant under the isometries of this metric, which are the [Lorentz group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group).

The Maxwell equations are manifestly Lorentz invariant if you simply write them as $\partial_\mu F^{\mu\nu} = 0$. They also give as a result that the speed of electromagnetic waves is $c$. *Since they are Lorentz invariant, this is true in all Lorentz-related frames*. Now, if you plug any path that represents motion with the speed $c$ into the metric, it is zero. Why? Parametrize the path as $t\mapsto (t,ct,0,0)$ (you can certainly Lorentz transform so that that is possible). Plug it in. Now,

$$\mathrm{d}s^2 = c^2\mathrm{d}t^2 - \mathrm{d}(ct)^2 = c^2\mathrm{d}t^2 - c^2\mathrm{d}t^2 = 0$$

And so the proper time along that path is $\tau = - \int ds^2 = 0$.

Comment: Thank you. As I understand you do not derive Tau directly from Maxwell equations, but Maxwell equations are referring to the spacetime interval equation?

Comment: The proper time $\tau$ is the path length as measured in the Minkowski metric (for a discussion why this is indeed proper time, see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/53334/why-do-clocks-measure-arc-length)). Maxwell's equations do not refer to anything, it simply turns out that they are Lorentz invariant.