# Confusion between time and proper time in Maxwell's Equations

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, inertial-frames

In special relativity, proper time is the time that measures a clock at rest. 
I understand how the coordinate time differs between observers moving relative to each other. But I cannot figure out the following:

If I replace coordinate time by proper time in Maxwell equations, are the equations still valid? something tells me that they are not, but I am not sure why not, because the clock that I will use to measure any predictions will agree with my proper time.

**Update**: Thanks for the answers, I realized I need to to make more clear what I am asking. Let us say I have a charged particle that is moving at some $v$. The spacetime interval of such particle after it moves during $dt$ will be $d\tau_{particle}^2=dt^2-dr^2$, where $c=1$. When I measure the particle speed, I use, by definition, $v=dx/dt$.
But the clock I use to measure the particle speed is equal to its proper time $dt=d\tau_{clock}$. If I have more than one particle, each labeled by $i$, I will have a different $d\tau_{particle }^i$ for each particle, but the same  $d\tau_{clock}$ for each. Thus, does it make sense at all to write Maxwell equations using proper time? But who's proper time? For instance, $v_i=\frac{dx_i}{d\tau_{clock}}\ne\frac{dx_i}{d\tau_{particle \space  i }}$. I guess you can define $v_{\tau \space i}=\frac{dx_i}{d\tau_i}$, and replace $v_i^2=\frac{v_{\tau\space i}^2}{1+v_{\tau\space i}^2}$, but I do not even know how to define the $\tau$ that I should use for a changing electric field.

The reason I would like to write everything in terms of $\tau$ instead of $t$ is the following: you can rewrite $d\tau^2=dt^2-dr^2$ as $dt^2=d\tau^2+dr^2$, and in principle you could consider $\tau$ instead of $t$ as the independent variable to describe the system. I know that people working in "Euclidean relativity" claim to do this (I tried a lot but still could not really follow their arguments beyond this point).  Do this make sense at all?

Comment: The answers to this similar question may help answer your question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/123403/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fields in Maxwell equations are defined at **all points** in spacetime. On the other hand, proper time is a property of a **trajectory** in spacetime. The notion of "writing Maxwell equations using proper time" cannot be defined.

Comment: The idea, in principle, was to replace a spacetime with points defined by (r,t) by another one with points defined by (r,$\tau$). I realized one big problem is  that I would have to use imaginary proper time for points outside the light cone. I do not know if that is the main problem or if there are others issues that I did not realized.

Comment: or as you said, perhaps it does not make any sense because the proper time is not a property of the spacetime point, but it depends on the trajectory too

Comment: Right. That's exactly my point.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as you are in an inertial frame (in special relativity). You can't be a photon, remember a photon has no proper time

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Maxwell equations will still be valid because the proper time is $\tau=\frac{t}{\gamma}$. If you are at rest then $\gamma=1$ and so $t=\tau$ and you will not notice any difference. If you are using the time from another reference frame you are just changing the variable, but the gamma factor is compensating.